# Apply function to some values in list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a function that takes a list of tasks, create threads and solves a complex task for each task.

To simplify lets just say it is this function:

```
def efficient_function_that_only_takes_a_list(list):
return [-x for x in list]
```

Now, all I need to do is to have a list and give it to the function:

```
efficient_function_that_only_takes_a_list(my_list)
```

My problem now is that I have realized that not all of the items in the list needs to be processed by the function. But I want to keep the order and only process some of them. This is what I came up with.

Anyone have a more pythonic way?

```
my_list = [3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def my_condition(x):
  return x%2 == 0 

def efficient_function_that_only_takes_a_list(list):
    return [-x for x in list]

#What I want: [1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7,-8,9]

# My attempt:
def apply_to_some(mylist, condition, function):
    valid = [(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if condition(x)]
    index, values = zip(*valid)
    results = function(values)
    for new_value, ix in zip(results,index):
        mylist[ix] = new_value
    return my_list

print apply_to_some(my_list, my_condition, efficient_function_that_only_takes_a_list) #=> [3, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, 9]
```

Edit: I really need my function to take a list and not a single item as I need to make it run efficiently i parallel like in this article: https://medium.com/p/40e9b2b36148

Comment: Despite the votes, I don't think my answer does meet your needs. Does your efficient function rely on getting a list, or could it be factored to a function applying to each item in the list?

Comment: Maybe if I write some kind of message queue. The function makes calls to a web service and needs to know size of list and such in order to run appropriate amount of threads/calls per second.

Comment: Well if you need the list, aside from a few tweaks that just reduce the line count, there's not much to improve on what you have

Comment: Please write that comment in your answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be neater to do something like:

```
def apply_to_some(mylist, condition, function):
    return [function(x) if condition(x) else x for x in mylist]
```

Although note that this form doesn't mutate `mylist`.

However, if your efficient function *relies* on a list, aside from a few tweaks that just reduce the line count, there's not much to improve on what you have.

Comment: @hirolau did you change this code somehow to make it work with your function (`efficient_function_that_only_takes_a_list`) that takes list on input and return list?

Comment: not good - you are creating new list but what if you need to change just 2 items in million items length list??

Answer (score 0):

Or if list comprehensions make your head spin, use map:

```
def apply_to_some(mylist, condition, function):
    return map(lambda x: function(x) if condition(x) else x, mylist)
```